# Formatting money in specific format

Tags: php, money-format

I've been fighting with the php `money_format()` function for a while now and can't it to work *exactly* as I'd like it to.

I want the number to be formatted like this: `€1.234,56`, and negative numbers `- €1.234,56`.

I've already tried all possible combinations between the following:

**Locales**

- nl_NL
- en_US
- it_IT
- de_DE

**Formats**

- `€ +!-#3.2n`
- `€ %-!4#8.2n`
- `%-4#8.2n`

None of them produce quite the right result. The most promising option right now is `it_IT` with `€ %-!4#8.2n`, which produces all the required formatting except for the position of the `-` sign, which is located behind the `€` instead of in front of it.

Which format/locale combination do I need to use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to better use the formatting options from the intl extension. Especially this one http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

There you can set on each call which locale should be used, as well as they use a library for the correct format strings of the used locale

Comment: Could you perhaps post an example of how to use this? I've never used it before :)

Comment: @cascer1 you can find examples on the site mentioned

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php#refsect1-numberformatter.formatcurrency-examples